# procmail insists in writing to /var/mail in macOS Sierra

Tags: mac-osx, procmail

I'm trying to configure `fetchmail` and `procmail` with a Google account. This is my `$HOME/.fetchmailrc`:

```
poll imap.gmail.com protocol IMAP 
   user "<email>" is jviotti here
   password '<password>'
   folder 'Inbox'
   keep
   ssl
mda 'procmail'
```

And this is my `$HOME/.procmailrc`:

```
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR/$LOGNAME/
LOGFILE=$MAILDIR/log/procmail
VERBOSE=on
```

I get the following errors from `procmail` when running `fetchmail -a -v` for every message that gets downloaded:

```
fetchmail: IMAP> A0005 FETCH 1 RFC822.HEADER
fetchmail: IMAP< * 1 FETCH (RFC822.HEADER {2865}
reading message <email>@gmail-imap.l.google.com:1 of 22 (2865 header octets) #
fetchmail: IMAP< )
fetchmail: IMAP< A0005 OK Success
fetchmail: IMAP> A0006 FETCH 1 BODY.PEEK[TEXT]
fetchmail: IMAP< * 1 FETCH (BODY[TEXT] {3983}
 (3983 body octets) *******************************.************************.***********.*****
fetchmail: IMAP< )
fetchmail: IMAP< A0006 OK Success
procmail: Couldn't create "/var/mail/jviotti"
 not flushed
fetchmail: IMAP> A0007 STORE 1 +FLAGS (\Seen)
fetchmail: IMAP< A0007 OK Success
```

Notice `procmail: Couldn't create "/var/mail/jviotti" not flushed`. For some reason, `procmail` insists on writing to `/var/mail` even though `MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail` and `DEFAULT=$MAILDIR/$LOGNAME/`.

Why is this the case?

By looking at `procmailrc` man page, I found that `ORGMAIL` defaults to `/var/mail/$LOGNAME`, and that `DEFAULT` defaults to `ORGMAIL`:

```
 ORGMAIL               /var/mail/$LOGNAME
                       (Unless -m has been specified, in which case it is unset)

 DEFAULT               $ORGMAIL
```

However even after setting `ORGMAIL` to something else in `$HOME/.procmailrc`, I get the same error/warning.

Notice that even though I get this error, my mail is correctly downloaded to `$HOME/Mail`.

**EDIT:** See the output of `procmail -v`. For some reason it still sets my system mailbox to /var/mail/jviotti.

```
$ procmail -v
procmail v3.22 2001/09/10
    Copyright (c) 1990-2001, Stephen R. van den Berg    <srb@cuci.nl>
    Copyright (c) 1997-2001, Philip A. Guenther         <guenther@sendmail.com>

Submit questions/answers to the procmail-related mailinglist by sending to:
        <procmail-users@procmail.org>

And of course, subscription and information requests for this list to:
        <procmail-users-request@procmail.org>

Locking strategies:     dotlocking, flock()
Default rcfile:         $HOME/.procmailrc
Your system mailbox:    /var/mail/jviotti
```

**EDIT 2**: See the following from `man procmail`:

> If no rcfiles and no -p have been specified on the command line,
>   procmail will, prior to reading $HOME/.procmailrc, interpret  commands
>   from /etc/procmailrc (if present).  Care must be taken when creating
>   /etc/procmailrc, because, if circumstances permit, it will be exe-
>   cuted with root privileges (contrary to the $HOME/.procmailrc file of
>   course).

Here is says that prior to reading my home configuration, it will read from `/etc/procmailrc`, however that file doesn't exist on my system, and even by explicitly passing `-p` (pointing to my home configuration), the system mailbox is still `/var/mail/jviotti`.

The man page also says:

> If no rcfile is found, or processing of the rcfile falls off the end,
>   procmail will store the mail in the default system mailbox.

What does "falls off the end" means?

Here is the output in the Procmail log file from one incoming message:

```
procmail: [49293] Tue Dec 13 14:29:20 2016 
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/Users/jviotti/Mail/jviotti/new/1481653760.49293_2.jviotti-rmbp.local" 
procmail: Notified comsat: "jviotti@0:/Users/jviotti/Mail/jviotti/new/1481653760.49293_2.jviotti-rmbp.local" 
From jviotti Tue Dec 13 14:29:20 2016 
 Subject: Re: [resin-io/etcher] chore: add support for snapshot builds (#968) 
  Folder: /Users/jviotti/Mail/jviotti/new/1481653760.49293_2.jviotti-r         8015
```

Comment: It looks like it isn't picking up your `.procmailrc` in the first place.  Can you add a `LOG=` statement to the top of your `.procmailrc` to see whether it is being executed at all?  (My guess is it isn't.)  See also http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Comment: FWIW the `not flushed` is apparently from Fetchmail.

Comment: The "system mailbox" simply indicates the system default; `procmail -v` is not reading your `.procmailrc` at all.

Comment: Your `.procmailrc` is attempting to deliver to `$HOME/Mail/$LOGNAME` i.e. probably `~/Mail/jviotti`.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Do you get anything in `$HOME/Mail/log/procmail`?  With `VERBOSE=on` there should be several lines of trace for each message.

Comment: @tripleee I added a dummy `LOG` and it gets executed, but that makes sense, given that my mail is being delivered to the location I specified (`$HOME/Mail/$LOGNAME`). The intention behind that directory is to deliver somewhere in my home directory. What is the best practice in that case?

Comment: There are a lot of logs at `$HOME/Mail/log/procmail`, but nothing relevant to this problem, just a list of emails subjects and the location they are being saved to (in `~/Mail/jviotti`)

Comment: See my second edit. Could it be that my rcfile is "falling off the end", as the man page describes it (although I don't understand what that means)?

Comment: It simply means it will deliver to `$DEFAULT` if you didn't have any matching recipe which made it deliver somewhere else and thereby stop processing.

Comment: Is the `LOGFILE` value the name of a directory, not a file?  This is an error, though I don't think it's the cause of your problem.  Anyway, set `LOGFILE` to a file (it doesn't need to exist) and you should at least then see what Procmail is doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50034/discussion-between-tripleee-and-jviotti).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you see is basically harmless, but it's Procmail telling you that it cannot create the default inbox with your current permissions -- you need to be root to create an empty mailbox.

Creating it manually with the right permissions should resolve this issue.

```
sudo install -o $USER -g mail -m 0600 /dev/null /var/mail/$USER
```

`procmail -v` simply reports what the compiled-in defaults are; it does not examine your `.procmailrc` at all (and if it did, any nontrivial recipe file would contain a large number of mailboxes with different conditions for when to write to which).

"Fall off the end" means if you have a `.procmailrc` which does not tell Procmail to deliver to a specific mailbox and stop processing (such as yours), the final action will be similar to if the last lines in your `.procmailrc` were

```
:0:
$DEFAULT
```

which also illustrates what an unconditional Procmail delivering recipe looks like.

The log file snippet from Procmail you posted shows that Procmail is actually executing your `.procmailrc` just fine.  The error message apparently happens while it's starting up, before it starts executing your `.procmailrc` (though I cannot repro this exactly, so this is mildly speculative).